# Connect to Git using SSH through Squid with SSL bump

Tags: git, github, openssh, squid

My goal is to setup squid proxy to allow only certain git repositories to be accessible (path)

I configured Squid to to use SSL Bump to trace and allow some URLs based on paths , I need to allow git clone via SSH, my squid configuration is as follows

```
http_access allow all
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl whitelist url_regex "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt"
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl SSL_ports port 22
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 22          # ssh
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl ssh_port port 22 # ssh
http_access allow ssh_port
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0
http_access allow all
http_access allow ssh_port
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny all
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/myCA.pem  options=NO_SSLv2
sslcrtd_program /usr/local/squid/libexec/security_file_certgen -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
always_direct allow all
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
ssl_bump splice all
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
strip_query_terms off
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

on windows I setup mingw with the following openssh client configuration

```
Host github.com
ServerAliveInterval 60
IdentitiesOnly yes
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 192.10.2.84 3128 %h %p ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User           github
ForwardAgent   yes
```

I am assuming that ~/.ssh/id_rsa is the github ssh key?
is this configuration right or wrong? I don't want to put ssh keys of the proxy in client configurations

here is the output of my git ssh

```
ssh git@github.com -Tvvv
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/developer/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/developer/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/developer/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/developer/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/corkscrew 172.16.2.84 3128 github.com 22 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: identity file /home/developer/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/developer/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Comment: How is this programming related? This is system administration.

Comment: this is git related

Comment: Sure, but not everything that's in some way related to git is programming. Hosting your own git server is also not on-topic and this looks like you're troubleshooting your proxy more than anything specifically about git. And I'm not just tell you this to enforce some arbitrary rules: I honestly think you've got a better chance of getting an answer on other sites in the SE network.

Comment: I don't know if it is limitation of github or I misconfigured the (proxy/client), what would you do instead, I am all ears? I am really stuck

Comment: I strongly suggest you not try to implement this filtering.  Broken proxies (HTTP proxies, antivirus and firewall software, TLS middleboxes, etc.) are a huge problem with Git because Git relies heavily on the standard functionality of HTTPS and SSH and proxies break that functionality.  You will likely break functionality and decrease security.  Don't do it.

Comment: it is a security requirement what other alternatives are possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to config:

`acl SSL_ports port 22`